# Is testing for cookies in a Django website standard?

Tags: django, cookies

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to develop my own prototype.  There are certain ragged edges with my code.  I'll lump together making the markup cross-browser compatible, detecting if JS is turned on for the client browser, and testing if cookies are enabled for client.

General question, but does pretty much every site out there test for cookies within their login view?  I know how to do this, I was just curious if it's so blatantly necessary.

Obviously, if cookies are disabled, the auth framework won't work.  How often do clients turn off cookies these days?

Might be a naive question or I may have answered myself but hey, I'm curious.

Brendan

Comment: When implementing functionality that's dependent on something the user can control, like turning JavaScript off/on or accepting cookies, I think it's always a good idea to inform the user that they will need [technology] in order to use whatever functionality, or they may not have an optimal experience.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I'm trying to put out a private Beta and I wasn't sure the degree to which people turn off JS or cookies.  I guess I should have phrased the question that way.

Comment: You're welcome. Opinions vary, but I don't think 99.9% of people could tell you what JavaScript *was*, much less how to turn it off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies and other authentication are handled by the session [Middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs) in Django. The pylons documentation has a bit more detailed explanation of how WSGI handles requests/responses, and how they make their way from the server, up into your code [here](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/concepts/).

Typically in Django, you use the @login_required decorator in your views, and the Session middleware handles the implementation details (like clients who have cookies disabled, as you mentioned).

For other stuff that you can put in a cookie, you use the [Httprequest.Cookies](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.COOKIES) array.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I actually know how to implement the sessions framework in Django (and the decorator).  I was more curious if cookie testing with request.session.set_test_cookie() is REALLY important or just a nice thing to add.  I wasn't aware of the Cookies array, that's really useful

Comment: Normally I do an ``if key in Httprequest.Cookies:`` statement, to check if the key actually exists.